# Webservice functional in SOAP UI but not app

Tags: jquery, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I've created a simple restful restful webservice that I've deployed on Glassfish. I've been able to use the webservice with SOAP UI but having problem doing the same thing with my presentation layer (simple html page).

This is the ajax function I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#getAllCustomers").click(function(){
    alert("Button is functional");
    $.ajax({
       type: "get",
       url: "http://localhost:8080/restfulpractice/webresources/customer",
       success: function(data){
           var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
           alert("Callback function is functional");
           $.each(jsonData, function(i, item){
              this.after("<br><br>"+item+"<br><br>");
           });
       }
    });
});
});
```

The button is functional. So nothing wrong with the listener. I've triple checked the url. What am I doing wrong? Can I somehow check if I get a response at all from the server without calling any service methods?

Edit: Ok thanks for answer. After checking the response in the browser I found out that I need to add a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. Whats the best way to do this if the method I'm using looks like this:

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/json"})
public List<Customer> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
We can send cross domain request via HTTP Request call(like in C#,JAVA) but as 
you say you are using simple html page and try to make service call via ajax.
Earlier we couldn't make cross domain call using ajax call but now we can. 
You just need to set crossDomain property true which false by default in ajax 
call and except jsonp data instead of json. It might be affect your service return 
data format.

Here is one link which you can prefer for more detailing and example.  
http://www.pureexample.com/jquery/cross-domain-ajax.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
It seems your trying to make cross domain call.In that case you should need to make proper configuration for cross domain call(not just simple ajax call). 
For testing your services, there are to many browser plugins are available which you can use. like Rest-client for fire-fox, Post-man in Chrome etc.
```